# curl json post request via terminal to a rails app

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, curl, terminal

I'm trying to create a user on my rails app with a curl command from os x terminal. No matter how I format the data, the app returns a responses that non of my validations have passed.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/1/users.json -i -X POST -d {"user":{"first_name":"firstname","last_name":"lastname","email":"email@email.com","password":"app123","password_confirmation":"app123"}}"
```

I've tried every variation. I've tried using [] brackets, I've tried user={data..} and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `$ rails c` and `User.create :first_name => 'John', :last_name => 'Smith', ...`?

Comment: @coryward: That would defeat the whole purpose of an API.

Comment: it really has me stumped

Comment: Hi, Bob maybe found the problem, but in case it could help, here is a post I found yesterday: http://squarism.com/2011/04/01/how-to-write-a-ruby-rails-3-rest-api/ It's about XML, but it might help. Best regards.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

First off, there is an extraneous " at the end of your command.

Try this

```
curl -v \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d ' {"user":{"first_name":"firstname","last_name":"lastname","email":"email@email.com","password":"app123","password_confirmation":"app123"}}' \
  http://localhost:3000/api/1/users
```

Comment: that was it. I figured out last night that it needs the -H Accept and Content-type.

Comment: Hi I cam calling a script like this: http://www.abc.com/?a=4&b={"x":"y"}. Can you tell me what it would look like in curl terminal??

Comment: hmmm in my case I needed to surround the target URL with quotes

Comment: I was able to remove the -v (verbose) switch and -H "Accept:..." from the above and it still works fine for me.

Comment: think you can remove -X POST as well since ur using -d

Comment: @Bob, can we pass multiple users?