# Curl json script

Tags: curl, libcurl, pycurl

I need to call a json script using curl terminal. following is the path I call from browser:

http://www.mydomain.com/?arg1=abc&arg2={"x":"y"}

But when I try this using curl it gives me error. Before posting this question I tried googling it couldn't find any specific answere. May be I am noob that couldn'd figured anything from this thread:

[curl json post request via terminal to a rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658510/curl-json-post-request-via-terminal-to-a-rails-app/5658904#comment12485332_5658904)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl command Bob posted is a POST request.

You are trying to provide the data using a GET request.

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://mydomain.com/?arg1=abc&arg2={'x':'y'}"
```

In case this doesn't work, could you post the error you're getting here?

Comment: This command doesn't run properly on windows cmd-prompt. I think the url should be double-quoted. But then again, how do we double-quate the Json-key-value pair?... btw I tried url double quoted and json single quoted without any success...

Comment: I just added the double quotes, try it now.

Comment: tried that already.. as mentioned in my above comment.. no success!!

Comment: Mind sharing your error then? or atleast the curl output. It's set to verbose, so it should give us plenty of information.

Comment: I got the problem. Actually I was trying this:
 
curl http://www.mydomain.com/?arg1=abc&arg2={%22x%22:%22y%22}

And the currect command is:

curl http://www.mydomain.com/?arg1=abc&arg2=%7B%22x%22:%22y%22%7D

Yeah I know I am getting silly lately..URL-encoding has been mentioned on the first page of curl docs. Silly chrome was giving me first URL, without encoding "{" and "}".