# Unable to pass params data to create a user

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, get

I have a rails app that accepts json request to create a user. A sign_up basically which is a GET. I can't create a user when i pass in this url `http://localhost:3000/sign_up.json?username=chalam&email=holy@yahoo.com&name=chalami&password=chalami`
I know I am passing the password in the open but that is not my concern here. i checked the logs and this is what i see

```
Started GET "/sign_up.json?username=chalam&email=holy@yahoo.com&name=chalami&password=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-28 10:37:37 +0700
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"username"=>"chalam", "email"=>"holy@yahoo.com", "name"=>"chalami", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

As you can see although the parameter `Parameters: {"username"=>"chalam", "email"=>"holy@yahoo.com", "name"=>"chalami", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}` clearly show that parameters are being passed, they are not being entered into the database `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1`
 Main problem is data from the params is not being "used" to create a User

One thing to note is I can create a user through the console in terminal. I will try to include all relevant information
rails version: 3.2.13 and
I am using thin instead of WEBBRICK

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :username
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :username

  def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end
  end

  def self.authenticate(username, password)
user = find_by_username(username)
if(user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,  user.password_salt))
    user
else
    nil
end
  end
end
```

My Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json
    def new
 @user = User.new
    end

    def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.save
  if @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => {:status => "200", :message => "Signed up successfully"}}
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
         puts @user.errors.inspect 
        format.json { render :json => {:status => "400", :message => "Failed"}}
    end
  end
  end

  def index
@user = User.all
render :json =>@user
  end
end
```

Comment: 1) Where is your controller code? 2) Please format your code so it is not simply code soup. 3) You're *creating* a resource on a *GET* request, undermining the environment that Rails has setup for you helping you build RESTful applications. 4) You are passing a password in the clear, thwarting your own security, nonchalantly. See #3.

Comment: By the way, Rails already supports securely hashed passwords with `has_secure_password` to make sure you don't make a bunch of the mistakes you're making (like re-hashing your password on every save).

Comment: Do you use devise gem?

Comment: @visnu No I'm not using the devise gem

Comment: @coreyward i have posted the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have come up with a solution and I thought I should post it, it might help people

Problem: I could not create a user using a Json response although I could do it through `rails console`

Mistakes:

1. I created a GET route to create a User which compromises security
2. I added the password field to `attr_accessor` and not to `attr_accessible`

Solutions:

1. changed the action from GET to POST(in the routes.rb). To create a user(for a POST) I used `curl`. In my case   my `curl` statement was 
   `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user":{"name":"name","username":"username","email":"email@email.com","password":"app123"}}' http://localhost:3000/sign_up`. Here is a useful post about [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658510/curl-json-post-request-via-terminal-to-a-rails-app?lq=1)

2.In my user model I included `attr_accessor :password` as well as `attr_accessible :password`