# POST request to test Rails API using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I am new to programming with Rails API.
 To test my Rails API, I need to build a manual POST request with data format like

{
  "user":
  {
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "name": "abc",
  }
}

I am trying to use Simple REST Client but not able to get the URL with data in the above format. How do I write the URL to get the data in the right format?

Comment: Refer this link for the post request  [API][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658510/curl-json-post-request-via-terminal-to-a-rails-app

Comment: can you give more details ? what are you using to test your API ? if you are using RSpec you could test the a post action to create a new user with this: `post :create, user: {email: "abc@gmail.com", name: "abc"}`